# Laravel 7 populate from SQL file with mutations

Tags: mysql, laravel, import, laravel-7

I am rewriting a big project from scratch. The DB is similar, but tables have been renamed, and fields have moved around.

I want to create commands in my Laravel 7.4 project that read MySQL dumps of each table and import them into the new DB. I can't just run the commands as everything has changed.

Is there an easy way to read the dump files so each insert command would give me an array with the data of that record from the old DB, so I can then modify that array as needed to use it to populate my models?

I would like to avoid having to read the file line by line and use regex to subtract what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing some regexes to do it line by line, and in the end, the code is quite manageable. I will need to write custom regex strings for each SQL file though.

```
public function handle()
{
    $sql = file_get_contents('./database/old_sql/language.sql');

    preg_match_all('/\(.*\)[\,;]/', $sql, $lines);

    foreach (array_shift($lines) as $line) {
        preg_match('/^\((\d+)\, \'(.*)\', (\d+)\)[\,;]$/', $line, $values);

        $language = Language::updateOrCreate([
            'languages.id' => $values[1]
        ], [
            'id'        => $values[1],
            'name'      => $values[2],
            'parent_id' => $values[3],
        ]);
    }
}
```

If someone has a better, cleaner solution, I'd be happy to hear about it.